# What is Java's most generic third party linked list?

Tags: java, list

According to my research, Java's [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) does not provide some commonly used methods like

- concat
- merge
- nextNode
- prevNode
- etc..

And so most answers I read say that I have to write my own custom linked list to cater my needs. Sure I can write a custom linked list. But I do not want to reinvent the wheel. And in the future I just might need to write another custom linked list with different but common methods.

So is there a third party open source linked list project out there that complements java's linked list with methods like the ones I mentioned above and more? Or is the LinkedList already complete and all I need to do is tweak its methods to suit my needs?

Comment: What would be the difference of `concat` and `merge` with `addAll(Collection<T>)`? Also, why do you exactly need `nextNode` and `prevNode`, I mean, what's the benefit from accessing the internals of the list without using an iterator?

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza well, those methods were just examples. What I'm looking for is a more generic and more complete linked list with more methods than java's original linked list. Or are you saying that java's linked list is already complete?

Comment: It depends on your real needs to decide if the implementation is *complete*, so it will be better if you post what you need/want to get more accurate help. By the way, I use `List` interface instead using `LinkedList` directly.

Comment: LinkedList.listIterator provides previous and next functionality.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, specifically I need a concat and next method, but as pointed out, I can use addAll and listIterator. Looking forward at the future though, I might need more methods that a LinkedList might not offer so I was asking if there was a generic linked list project out there. If you think that there is no need for a third party please answer so that I can accept/comment on it.

Comment: It is not that I don't think you don't need it, but as long as it doesn't shows as a problem then you should not worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Commons has a bunch of Lists you can use.  See http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/package-summary.html

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. So basically there's no need to create a custom linked list? All the functionality I might need has already been written?

Comment: That's what you'll likely find in most cases.  The only times I've needed to write such things myself are when I don't have access to particular libraries for whatever reason.  For instance, I can't access Apache Commons from GWT.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly get a ListIterator instance that gives you next() and previous() using the listIterator() method.

I usually use the for loop built-in since Java 6, since it seems clearer and easier, but I have occasionally fallen back on iterators when I needed something more elaborate.  I'm not aware of any third party libraries.  I'm also not aware of any common Data-Structure functionality that isn't already there, although they do tend of have their own nomenclature.